# Why passing char* to a string argument generates a compilation error?

Tags: c++

I was prototyping with the following code.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>


template<class container, class value> class Add {
public:
    Add(){};
    ~Add(){};
    void add_value(container& cont, value& val){
        std::for_each(cont.begin(), cont.end(), [&val](value& v){v +=val;});
    };
};


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Add<std::vector<std::string>, std::string> a;
    std::vector<std::string> vec = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
    std::string foo= "1";
    a.add_value(vec, foo); // compiles fine
    a.add_value(vec, "1"); // generates an error
    return 0;
}
```

and i got the following error

```
template.cpp:28:25: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’
```

Why it's not possible to pass a `char*` to a `string` argument ?

As far as i know an implicit conversion will be executed in order to convert the `char*` to `std::string` and the result will be passed to the function.

Comment: Function needs to take a const reference. Non-const references can't be bound to temporaries, such as those produced by converting "1" to a string. The error message tells you that.

Comment: I'm being curious here. why non-const references can't be bound to rvalues ?

Comment: Because the C++ Standard says not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined the `add_value` as following:

```
void add_value(container& cont, value& val)
```

Where the string is a non-const reference, the compiler expect this reference to point to a modifiable variable somewhere else.

However, when you pass a `const char[]`, even if this type could be converted to a string (in case it would compile), it is done on the fly and the string is not modifiable. Actually, the `char*` is not modifiable neither. That is why your code do not compile.

You may define your function as following and it would work:

```
void add_value(container& cont, const value& val)
```

Comment: Not me but you have several things that are a bit wrong: `"1"` is not a `char*`, but a `const char[]`. It can decay to `const char*`, but will never be `char*`. Also, the reason why it doesn't compile isn't because the string literal is not modifiable, but because OP is trying to bind a prvalue to a lvalue reference.

Comment: Your phrasing, “even if this type could be converted to a string”, implies that it cannot. In fact, a `const char*` (or, as is actually the case, `const char[2]`) can be converted to a `std::string`, which is why just making the parameter a `const&` works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. @Rakete1111: Not sure that a string literal is a prvarlue, I am missing something?

Comment: @AdrianMaire I'm not sure either, but any other value category doesn't make sense. But it looks like [I'm wrong](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue)! Now I'm confused...

Comment: @AdrianMaire Ok got it. It is in fact an lvalue, but calling `add_value` results in the construction of a temporary `std::string` object. *That* is a prvalue, and so you can't assign it to a lvalue reference. Actually, I said nothing wrong, because I never talked about string literals in that context :P

Comment: I guess is a nice additional info related to the question.